# Having Error: DeliveryZone.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am getting `Error: DeliveryZone.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model` In `sequelize 5` while I tried to build a relationship with other models.

I have searched on google and StackOverflow but I could not find the appropriate answer for my case.

I have already lost my 12 hours!! Can anyone help me to figure out what is problem here?

Here I paste my snippet:

**DeliveryZone.ts**

```
import {DataTypes, Associatio, Model, Sequelize,} from 'sequelize';
import {DeliveryHero} from "./DeliveryHero";
import {DeliveryHeroZone} from "./DeliveryHeroZone";
const sequelizeConfig = require('../config/sequelizeConfig.json');

export class DeliveryZone extends Model{
  public id!: number; // Note that the `null assertion` `!` is required in strict mode.
  public name!: string;
  public status!: string;
  public created_by_id!: number | null; // for nullable fields
  public updated_by_id!: number | null; // for nullable fields
  public managed_by_id!: number
  public zone_id!: string

  // timestamps!
  public readonly created_at!: Date;
  public readonly updated_at!: Date;

}


const { database, username, password, params } = sequelizeConfig;
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, params);

DeliveryZone.init({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique:true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    allowNull: false
  },
  status: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
    allowNull: false
  },
  created_by_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER
  },
  updated_by_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER
  },
  managed_by_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  zone_id: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    allowNull: false,
  },
},{
  tableName: 'delivery_zones',
  sequelize: sequelize,
  underscored: true
});

DeliveryZone.hasMany(DeliveryHeroZone, {
  foreignKey: 'delivery_zone_id',
  as: 'delivery_zones'
});


DeliveryZone.sync({force: true})
```

**DeliveryHeroZone.ts**

```
import {DataTypes, Model, Sequelize,} from 'sequelize';
import {DeliveryZone} from "./DeliveryZone";
import {DeliveryHero} from "./DeliveryHero";
const sequelizeConfig = require('../config/sequelizeConfig.json');

export class DeliveryHeroZone  extends Model{
  public id!: number; // Note that the `null assertion` `!` is required in strict mode.
  public status!: string;
  public created_by_id!: number | null; // for nullable fields
  public updated_by_id!: number | null; // for nullable fields
  public delivery_hero_id!: number;
  public delivery_zone_id!: number;

  // timestamps!
  public readonly created_at!: Date;
  public readonly updated_at!: Date;

}


const { database, username, password, params } = sequelizeConfig;
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, params);

DeliveryHeroZone.init({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique:true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  status: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
    allowNull: false
  },
  created_by_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER
  },
  updated_by_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER
  },
  delivery_hero_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  delivery_zone_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
},{
  tableName: 'delivery_hero_zones',
  sequelize: sequelize,
  underscored: true,
});


DeliveryHeroZone.belongsTo(DeliveryHero, {
  foreignKey: "delivery_hero_id",
  onDelete: "CASCADE"
})
DeliveryHeroZone.belongsTo(DeliveryZone, {
  foreignKey: "delivery_zone_id",
  onDelete: "CASCADE"
})

DeliveryHeroZone.sync({ force: true})
```